# How Can I Create A Dump File of Running Process in Linux

Tags: linux

In windows, It is easy to get a dump file. right? but In Linux, I don't know create dump file.

Answer (score 1):

`gcore` is one way to do it.  There are more complex ways involving interrupting it with a debugger and injecting a `fork()` and `raise(SIGABRT)` or similar.  (`gcore` may not be installed by default.)

Comment: thank you for your answear. Would you give me a specific information??

Comment: http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?gcore or install it using your system's package manager and do `man gcore`.

Comment: oh I see.. and then? How can I use this manual?

Comment: By reading it?  I can't run the command for you...